# Fast way of swapping Red/Blue bytes using ScanLine

Tags: delphi, colors, pixel, scanline

Currently, I loop the `Canvas.Pixels[]` property and read each pixel on a canvas to swap Red/Blue bytes around (for specific reasons). However, it takes an average of 2 seconds per picture, and I have over 8,000 pictures I need to convert (overnight). I understand I can use a method of `ScanLine` to accomplish this much faster, but I know nothing about `ScanLine` - it's a much lower level of coding than I'm comfortable with. What's the fastest way to accomplish this? I'm willing to wait some time for this to run through, but it would still be nice if I could chop that time in half or more.

Right now, this is the procedure I use:

```
procedure SwapBytes(var Bmp: TBitmap);
var
  X, Y: Integer;
  R, G, B: Byte;
  C: TColor;
begin
  for Y := 0 to Bmp.Height - 1 do begin
    for X := 0 to Bmp.Width - 1 do begin
      C:= Bmp.Canvas.Pixels[X,Y];
      R:= GetRValue(C);
      G:= GetGValue(C);
      B:= GetBValue(C);
      Bmp.Canvas.Pixels[X,Y]:= RGB(B, G, R)
    end;
  end;
end;
```

*Added Note*: An initial conversion of over 8,000 images is the first step of why I need this. However, I also will be using the same thing in our software to automatically convert any image on the spot, as needed. So a third-party converter won't work, because I cannot distribute this to our clients.

Comment: There's a sample in the [docwiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/ScanLine_(Delphi)) that shows using ScanLine and accessing RGB triples.

Comment: Oh, you made out that you were writing a utility to convert your images. "I have over 8,000 pictures I need to convert (overnight)". Never mind.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks, looking into it...

Comment: [`Here`](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29173) is also a good reading about scanlines.

Comment: @Jerry Dodge, you might not even need this if you hack the `jpeg.pas` source... (see your other question)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would try something like follows. This version is only for 24-bit bitmaps:

```
procedure SwapRedBluePixels(ABitmap: TBitmap);
var
  X: Integer;
  Y: Integer;
  Red: Byte;
  Pixel: PRGBTriple;
begin
  // check for the bit depth, it must be 24-bit if you use PRGBTriple pointer
  // for line scan; if it wouldn't the iterated line pointers would point to 
  // another place in the memory
  if ABitmap.PixelFormat <> pf24bit then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Your bitmap has color depth different from 24-bit');
    Exit;
  end;
  // iterate through the image vertically
  for Y := 0 to (ABitmap.Height - 1) do
  begin
    // access the line of pixels and get the pointer to the first pixel of 
    // that line
    Pixel := ABitmap.ScanLine[Y];
    // iterate through the scanned line pixels horizontally
    for X := 0 to (ABitmap.Width - 1) do
    begin
      // store the pixel's red channel value
      Red := Pixel.rgbtRed;
      // modify the pixel's red channel value
      Pixel.rgbtRed := Pixel.rgbtBlue;
      // modify the pixel's blue channel value
      Pixel.rgbtBlue := Red;
      // increment to get the next pixel pointer of the scanned line
      Inc(Pixel);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

***Update 2:***

This version is for 24-bit and 32-bit bitmaps:

```
procedure SwapRedBluePixels(ABitmap: TBitmap);
var
  X: Integer;
  Y: Integer;
  Red: Byte;
  Size: Integer;
  Pixels: PByteArray;
begin
  // check the color depth and set the size of the pixel arrangement
  case ABitmap.PixelFormat of
    pf24bit: Size := SizeOf(TRGBTriple);
    pf32bit: Size := SizeOf(TRGBQuad);
  else
    // if the image is not 24-bit or 32-bit go away
    begin
      ShowMessage('Your bitmap has unsupported color depth!');
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

  // iterate through the image vertically
  for Y := 0 to (ABitmap.Height - 1) do
  begin
    // access the line of pixels and get the pointer to the first pixel of
    // that line
    Pixels := ABitmap.ScanLine[Y];
    // iterate through the scanned line pixels horizontally
    // for 24-bit images the pixels are stored like
    // B -> G -> R -> B -> G -> R etc.
    // for 32-bit images the pixels are stored like
    // B -> G -> R -> A -> B -> G -> R -> A etc.
    // so we can simply use e.g. byte array and iterate through
    // it, if we have 24-bit image, we have to read each element,
    // if 32-bit we have to skip the alpha (reserved) channel
    for X := 0 to (ABitmap.Width - 1) do
    begin
      // store the pixel's red channel value
      Red := Pixels^[(X * Size) + 2];
      // modify the pixel's red channel value
      Pixels^[(X * Size) + 2] := Pixels^[(X * Size)];
      // modify the pixel's blue channel value
      Pixels^[(X * Size)] := Red;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Looks like a good one, thanks. But I just thought of something - is there a way that `ScanLine` can read just one channel (1 for red and 1 for blue) and just swap those lines around?

Comment: @Jerry There aren't separate lines for red and blue. It's a line of pixels. That's just how bitmaps are.

Comment: Nice, that chopped it to about 1/3 the time

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, understood - but like maybe it could skip over a certain amount of bytes as it's reading the raw data or something - to only gather the red and blue bytes, and work directly in the image's data maybe.

Comment: Sorry, if it's a silly question, but... shouldn't the retrieved and then modified line be somehow put back to the source bitmap?

Comment: @AndriyM Actually no, that's the beauty of `ScanLine` is it works directly with the image it came from.

Comment: Ah, I think I see now, you are storing the pointer, which means you are sort of operating on the source directly.

Comment: @AndriyM, they're never taken out. :) `ScanLine` is a pointer to the actual bitmap memory for a row of pixels.

Comment: @Jerry Dodge & Ken White: Yup, figured that too, thanks anyway!

Comment: @JerryDodge Skipping over one byte doesn't help. An entire cache line will be read. It still doesn't sound very fast.

Comment: @François, very good point, thanks. The bitmaps containing alpha are less usual. The most common are 24-bit. I'll modify my answer a little bit (I just copied it from my old post).

Comment: Since the OP is converting RGB JPEGs, they will indeed by 24 bit.

Comment: Thank you for the fix, but to be safe, is there any way you can make it work for both 24 and 32? Because out of thousands of pictures, I have no clue if 100% of them really are 24bit and need to handle them properly - it would presumably mess up a 32bit image.

Comment: @Jerry, I've added the version which should support both, 24-bit and 32-bit images. It exploits from the same channel arrangement for those bit depths (except that 32-bit images has one extra channel for alpha, so you have to skip it if you want to get it compatible for this purpose).